# How to decode, and then format, tagged LocalDateTime value

Tags: json, clojure, clojurescript, reagent, transit

This is my *Clojurescript* function,

```
(defn message-list [messages]
  (println messages) ;; stmt#1
  [:ul.messages
   (for [{:keys [timestamp message name]} @messages]
     ^{:key timestamp}
     [:li
      [:time (.toLocaleString timestamp)] ;; stmt#2
      [:p message]
      [:p " - " name]])])
```

`stmt#1` is printing,

```
#<Atom: [{:id 1, :name Adeel Ansari, :message Hello, from the other side., 
          :timestamp #object[Transit$TaggedValue [TaggedValue: LocalDateTime, 2020-01-13T18:19:50.552]]}]>
```

and `stmt#2` is printing,

```
[TaggedValue: LocalDateTime, 2020-01-13T18:19:50.552]
```

**Now, I would like to print it as, say, `13/01/2020 18:19`; how should I go about it?** I've no idea how to decode tagged-values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the value from the `TaggedValue` using `.-rep`, and then, you can parse that `String` using some library.

For example you can parse the date, using [cljc.java-time](https://github.com/henryw374/cljc.java-time), like this:

```clj
(let [tv (t/tagged-value "LocalDateTime" "2019-01-01T11:22:33.123")]
    (cljc.java-time.local-date-time/parse (.-rep tv))) => #object[LocalDateTime 2019-01-01T11:22:33.123]
```

Or you can use [Tick](https://juxt.pro/tick/docs/index.html); then your code would look something like,

```clj
(ns xx.yy.zz
  (:require ..
            [tick.locale-en-us]
            [tick.alpha.api :as t]
            ..
            ))
...
  (defn message-list [messages]
    ...
       [:li
        [:time (t/format (t/formatter "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") (t/parse (.-rep timestamp)))]   
        ...]
    ...)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you would provide a handler function directly to transit so that it can convert the value at read time. The same must have been done on the server to create the TaggedValue in the first place.

When constructing the [reader](http://cognitect.github.io/transit-cljs/cognitect.transit.html#var-reader) you can supply

```
:handlers {"LocalDateTime" (fn [string-val] (parse-the-timestamp string-val))}
```

The formatting should be delayed until needed but a TaggedValue should ideally not make it out of the read function since it couples your code to the transit implementation.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas; this sounds like a very good suggestion. Actually, I was looking into handler, but had no idea about how-to. Your snippet gave me a hint.